Template overloading constructors resolution with v143 tools fails
Why does this code compile ok with v142 tools, but breaks with v143?
#include <memory>

namespace H {
    template <typename T>
    struct shared_ptr : public std::shared_ptr<T> {
        using _MyBase = std::shared_ptr<T>;
        using _MyBase::shared_ptr;
    };
}


int main() {
    H::shared_ptr<int> sharedDirectInitializaiton0{ nullptr };
    H::shared_ptr<int> sharedDirectInitializaiton1{ std::shared_ptr<int>{} }; // (v143) error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'H::shared_ptr<int>'
    H::shared_ptr<int> sharedCopyInitialization0 = nullptr;
    H::shared_ptr<int> sharedCopyInitialization1 = std::shared_ptr<int>{}; // (v143) error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::shared_ptr<T>' to 'H::shared_ptr<int>'
    return 0;
}

Same result in Demo between "x64 msvc v19.29 VS16.11" and "x64 msvc v19.30 VS17.0". However, if build with "/permissive-" (No) flag with v143 tools the build is ok.
Another example:
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Base {
    Base() {};
    Base(std::nullptr_t) {}
    
    template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U, T>::value>>
    Base(Base<U>) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T> {
    using _MyBase = Base<T>;
    using _MyBase::_MyBase;
};


int main() {
    // OK for both v142 | v143 tools ("x64 msvc v19.29 VS16.11" | "x64 msvc v19.latest").
    Derived<int> derived1{ nullptr };     // #1
    Derived<int> derived2 = nullptr;      // #2 'Derived' must using _MyBase::_MyBase.

    // FAIL with v143 but work with v142.
    Derived<int> derived3{ Base<int>{} }; // #3
    Derived<int> derived4 = Base<int>{};  // #4 'Base' must define template <typename U, ...> Base(Base<U>) {}.

    // Errors:
    // #3 -- error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Derived<int>'
    // #4 -- error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'Base<T>' to 'Derived<int>'
    return 0;
}

Demo2

Code fails to compile with other compilers (in C++11 or later) Demo. msvc was not compliant.

The code is already rejected by all 3 compilers(including msvc). Demo. Always use /permissive- to be sure that you're using msvc in standard conformant way.

When inheriting constructors from a dependent base class, you must repeat the (template) name used to identify the base after the :: rather than using another alias for it (even the injected-class-name).

"using _MyBase::_MyBase" does not solve the problem. I edited the question, added another example with simple classes that reproduce the problem. Maybe the latest C++ compiler is stricter than the previous one? One solution I see is to use template "Derived" Ctor, which forwards arguments to "Base".
